# UITableViewController crash on iOS6 simulator

Tags: crash, uitableview, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm working on a project and just update to Xcode 4.5 and i'm using iOS 6 simulator.
Now i'm getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] loaded the "FeedController" nib but didn't get a
>   UITableView.'

It's strange cause I do not have any NIB file for this controller since it is only a table:

```
@interface FeedController : UITableViewController <EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate>

- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource;
- (void)doneLoadingTableViewData;

@end
```

This controller is loaded from a Tab Controller, it alloc the FeedController without problem, but when you press the tab button to show the feed it crashes with that error.
It was working good on ios4 and ios5 simulators and devices.

Clean & Build project didn't help.

Anyone with same problem?

Comment: Can you give the code you are initializing the UITableViewController with?

Comment: Initializing simply with: FeedController *controller = [[FeedController alloc] init]; It's super weird, i also had (in same project) other controllers inheriting from UITableViewController that doens't have any problems, and functionality is identical.

Comment: Try using initWithStyle: instead of init on the FeedController.

Answer (score 0):

Does the answer listed here help? [nib but didn't get a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221802/nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview)

If not, is your `UITabBarController` created from a NIB that somehow specifies a non-`UITableView` view for the `FeedController` tab?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add this:

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```