# Xcode/IOS debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am a total newbie with objective C and IOS programming trying to follow along with a tutorial on the Apple Website.

I got to the point in the Apple tutorial where you add an unwind segue to the Add to-do page.

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1
```

I successfully added unwind segues to both the Cancel and Done buttons.

However, when I compiled the program, while it compiles, it no longer lets me click on + to get to the add to-do page.

When the simulator initially loads, it is fine.  But when I click on +, Xcode appears in front of the simulator and in the debugger it says what is below.

Note I have no experience in debugging.  What appears in editor is main.m and the following is in right side of debug section at bottom:

```
2014-12-03 13:28:54.854 single-nocore[20692:1523451] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "vXZ-lx-hvc-view-kh9-bI-dsS" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102eabf35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101265bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102eabe6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000101785415 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 249
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001015c87f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001015c8c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000101600d3b -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 149
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001015a8ec2 -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 101
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001015a6b0d __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 108
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001014c6331 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001014c61ab _afterCACommitHandler + 516
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102de0dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102de0d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102dd6b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102dd6486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104bae9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001014a3420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  single-nocore                       0x0000000100d39b23 main + 115
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000103b5c145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Please post your code...
 Take a look at this link as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234875/loaded-the-nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview?lq=1

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to push a UITableViewController but the storyboard doesn't have a table view wired.  Can you include a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: I fixed it using the accepted answer in NickCatib's comment of changing UITableView Controller to UITable Controller in the .h file for the header file of the destination view. Don't really know why this fixed it but it did.  Maybe it had something to do with originally Apple's tutorial set up segue using navigation and then said to undo that and set it up as modal...