# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException? 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: ios, uitableview

Today I ran my code that hasn't had any errors until now. Whenever someone clicks on the middle tab at the bottom the app crashes completely but all the other tabs work fine. Here's the call stack:

```
2014-07-01 16:27:19.848 Test Web[66180:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "lwz-qR-aDm-view-tp0-bK-7dP" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017f11e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015708e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017f0fbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x0050418e -[UITableViewController loadView] + 281
    4   UIKit                               0x0034f0d3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    5   UIKit                               0x0034f5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    6   UIKit                               0x0038711f -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 407
    7   UIKit                               0x00386943 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 63
    8   UIKit                               0x00382bed -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 281
    9   UIKit                               0x00382acc -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 180
    10  UIKit                               0x0038683f -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 312
    11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01582880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    12  UIKit                               0x002323b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    13  UIKit                               0x00232345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    14  UIKit                               0x004f6629 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 479
    15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0158282b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    16  UIKit                               0x002323b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    17  UIKit                               0x00232345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    18  UIKit                               0x00333bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    19  UIKit                               0x00333fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    20  UIKit                               0x00333c06 -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 48
    21  UIKit                               0x004fb23d -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 123
    22  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01582880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    23  UIKit                               0x002323b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    24  UIKit                               0x00232345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    25  UIKit                               0x00333bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    26  UIKit                               0x00333fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    27  UIKit                               0x00333243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    28  UIKit                               0x00271ddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    29  UIKit                               0x002729d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    30  UIKit                               0x002445f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    31  UIKit                               0x0022e353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0177a77f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0177a10b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x017971ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x017969d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x017967eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x037e55ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x037e542b GSEventRun + 104
    39  UIKit                               0x00230f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    40  Test Web                            0x000031fd main + 141
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e38701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I've tried looking for a solution to this error and checking back over the storyboard but found nothing out of place. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: Maybe duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221802/nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview ?

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController needs an UITableView connected to it's view property. 
Also make sure that the delegate and datasource are properly connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you use xib, make sure that UITableView connected to fileOwner.tableView property.
You probably use xib file to make interface.

[image]

Comment: No, i use storyboard its xcode 5 but yeah it is connected but im working on getting the UITableView implemented in as well

Comment: Can you add brake to viewdidLoad: method and watch, where is program will fail? @user3795631

Comment: Ok i think i put the break in the right spot but i got the same result