# Connecting a PFUITableView and Detail View using Parse and Swift in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform, segue

I am trying to set up a table view from a Parse database.  Each cell should contain several pieces of data about one object (coded in Parse as what and `where`).  When tapped, it should transition to a new page showing all available data about that object (including username, and when).

Here's my code for the table view:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class TableView: PFQueryTableViewController {

override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "ItemRequest"
    self.textKey = "what"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "ItemRequest")
        query.orderByAscending("what")
        return query
}

//override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath       
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath     
indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! PFTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let what = object?["what"] as? String {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = what
    }
    if let `where` = object?["`where`"] as? String {
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = `where`
    }

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: 
    NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: tableView)
    }


    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController


    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        detailScene.currentObject = (objects?[row] as! PFObject)
    }

}
```

}

And the code for the detail view:

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class DetailViewController: TableView {

var currentObject : PFObject?

@IBOutlet var whatis: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var whereis: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var whenis: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var whois: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var priceis: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        if let object = currentObject {
            whatis.text = (object["what"] as! String)
            whereis.text = (object["`where`"] as! String)
            priceis.text = (object["price"] as! String)
            whenis.text=(object["when"] as! String)
        }
    }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

When I run, the table shows only the "what" data points, and nothing else.  When I try to select a row, it does not segue to the next screen (and I did segue set up in the storyboard).  No error appears.  Any help would be greatly appreciated- new to Swift and programming in general!

Update: tried the code suggested below and got a Thread1 Signal Sigabrt error.  Error log below:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "uB8-vY-KsT-view-Ky8-TR-c7F" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00c24746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0295ea97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00c2466d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   UIKit                               0x01aeb772 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 289
    4   ParseStarterProject                 0x0010c41b -[PFQueryTableViewController loadView] + 51
    5   UIKit                               0x018e5aef -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    6   UIKit                               0x018e6095 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    7   UIKit                               0x01f472cc -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 75
    8   UIKit                               0x018ba4f1 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 113
    9   UIKit                               0x018f36cc -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 2134
    10  UIKit                               0x018f6382 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 345
    11  UIKit                               0x018f61d4 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 224
    12  UIKit                               0x018fb02b -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 213
    13  UIKit                               0x01b38d32 -[UIStoryboardShowSegue perform] + 143
    14  UIKit                               0x01d8c297 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 217
    15  UIKit                               0x018e8330 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 72
    16  ParseStarterProject                 0x00106dec _TFC19ParseStarterProject9LendItems9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 268
    17  ParseStarterProject                 0x00106e99 _TToFC19ParseStarterProject9LendItems9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 89
    18  UIKit                               0x0189c2a6 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1559
    19  UIKit                               0x0189c451 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 285
    20  UIKit                               0x018a1795 __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    21  UIKit                               0x017ab862 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    22  UIKit                               0x017ab80d _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 415
    23  UIKit                               0x017ab622 _afterCACommitHandler + 549
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00b4586e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00b457b0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00b3b1ea __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00b3aa5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00b3a88b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x03fea2c9 GSEventRunModal + 192
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x03fea106 GSEventRun + 104
    31  UIKit                               0x01781106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    32  ParseStarterProject                 0x000fe524 main + 180
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x030a2ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: tableView)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        detailScene.currentObject = (objects?[row] as! PFObject)
    }

}
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221802/nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview