# identifier "UIViewController-Mfe-qf-rSO" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

How do I get the the UITableView?

I tried to reference [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221802/nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview)

The error is generate by this code:

```
let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DrinkTableViewCell", owner: self.commentTableView, options: nil)?.first as! DrinkTableViewCell
```

Here is an image of what the UIController is referring to:

[image]

Here's the error code I get from it:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-Mfe-qf-rSO" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you are using custom cells in tableview.

```
let myString = "reused"
            var cell:MenuCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(myString) as? MenuCell
            if cell == nil
            {
                 let nib_Array:NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MenuCell", owner: self, options: nil)
                cell = nib_Array.objectAtIndex(0) as! MenuCell
            }
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```